# I want to create a web API in ASP.NET C# that needs to run scheduled jobs from the app lets A with the inputs present in B(external system)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

Since, A and B are two different system altogether, there is no way to connect these two apps directly. So, I want to create my app in such a way that It will connect to an azure function and that azure function will act as a mediator that can get inputs(Payload) from the external system B and run the jobs of A. On this, the  complexity of the  Payload generation  & API Call is shared by the Azure & On-premise EXE. The EXE will call the right Azure Job and the Job workflow is handled by Azure . Please help me the way to build the API/console app in C#.

Without Azure function, I am not getting any options to connect to any external app to get the payloads. Need to know about the way to connect to Azure so that azure can act as a mediator to connect these two external apps.

Comment: So, you  can modify B? And what does it mean *run the jobs of A*. Does that mean it needs to call A somehow or is a job something that can be done withouth calling A? We need more info to be able to help.

Comment: A is basically a set of jobs that needs the input from B(external sys). I need to create an API sol that can take the help of Azure function to run the jobs of A by taking the input payloads from B with all the required authentication and validations

Comment: Yes, but those jobs of A can run on Azure withouth being dependend on A?

Comment: @PeterBons, correct.

Comment: How about modifying B so it puts a message with the needed input on a queue (azure servicebus or storage queue) and have a queue triggered function that runs the job? Then the azure function does not need to call B with all the required authentication and validations since B pushes the info need to process the job to the queue

Comment: So you meant what I am searching with Azure function, that can be done by azure service bus or storage queue. Do you have any existing link or some reference that I can go through to understand/look on the work flow.

Comment: [Azure Service Bus documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus/)
[Azure Service Bus tutorials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus/tutorials/)
Azure Storage Queue:
[Azure Storage Queue documentation:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/)
[Azure Storage Queue tutorials:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/tutorials/)
[Get started with Azure Queue Storage using .NET](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues.md)